# Interrupted Mac App Store Download - Xcode

Tags: mac-appstore, xcode

After losing my connection while downloading Xcode 4.2.1, the App Store has removed it from available updates and under purchases it says I am up to date (even though the date of the my installed version is before the latest update date). I have tried to do:

```
defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
```

And then use the Debug menu item after restarting the App Store using these instructions:

http://www.ryanragle.com/index.php?/site/comments/where-does-the-mac-app-store-download-temp-files-to

Is there any other way to directly download 4.2.1 or to force the App Store to clear its cache, short of removing Xcode entirely?

Comment: i know this will seem too obvious, but it saved me with a botched mavericks.
could there be an 'install xcode' app in your applicaitons folder -- or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Click on Purchases by keeping the ⌥ key pressed (option key). It will need 10 seconds to initiate the tab (more or less), but afterwards you'll be able to re-download any purchased app.

Comment: I found that too in the link above, but it still shows all my purchases with "installed" next to the old xcode.

Comment: Even if you wait a lot of time with the ⌥ key pressed? And what about the "Check for unfinished downloads" menu item?

Comment: nope, it saws all purchases complete. I think you need to uninstall before you can install a purchase...